# Sniff email content inside network

Tags: sniffer

I use Cain and Abbel and I want to see the email content.
If you help me becouse I don`t know to see the content.
I see the email in the section password but I need to see the email content .
I can simply with Wireshark?

Thank for what you said,I understood and I made ARP Poisoning.So I see at Passwords->HTTP two URLs:www.yahoo.com and one hsrd.yahoo.com after this things what I need to do to see the email content like : Hello..what I wrote in email.

I use now Cain and Abel.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify this some more? What do you mean "section password"? Shure you could do that with wireshark as long as the emails aint encrypted. Sniff your email traffic then right klick on some smtp packets you acctually sniffed. Then select "Follow TCP stream" there you should see the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Wireshark will do the job.

If you want to sniff your own mails just start it on the corresponding interface.

If you want to sniff all mails in the network you have to somehow put yourself in a [man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) position. You could use Cain for that if you have it installed anyway and it supports ARP poisoning, which is one possible method.

After sniffing for a while you can check "Statistics -> Conversations -> TCP" for the TCP sessions. In there you can select one and click on "Follow Stream" to see everything.

This will only work for unencrypted mails transfered over unencrypted protocols of course.